# How to convert lat lon to Point on MYSQL update

Tags: mysql

I want to migrate the data from a table to another. The first table has 2 columns, latitude and longitude. The second has one Point column. On the transfer, I want to turn table 1
's latitude and longitude into a single point in table 2.

UPDATE:
   I broke the operation in two. I did the regular insert based on the other table. Now I want to update the Point based on the source table with Latitude and longitude.

I came up with this query but it hangs... Any suggestions on how to optimize it? (I also don't think it works, since it has never finished)

```
UPDATE zip.zip_points AS dest
INNER JOIN zip.zip_codes_2 AS src ON dest.zip = src.zip
SET dest.lat_lon = Point(src.latitude, src.longitude);
```

Comment: Have you made any research on that?

Comment: Yes, I just don't use sql often, so I'm not sure where I would assign the new column. And I'm still researching...

Comment: uhm, "assign the new column" ? You could put any expression `SELECT 1+1, ...`

Comment: Something like lat_lon = Point(Latitude, Longitude)

Comment: You don't need `=` sign here - just `SELECT <expression>`

Comment: Ok, I updated my question to make it easier I hope